# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'blah'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, database, macos, localhost

I try to log in with `mysql -u blah -p` and I put in the correct password and I still get this error. I have even tried to use root user by `mysql -u root` I have also tried with the `-p` to no avail.

When I try to start or stop the server with: `mysql.server stop/start` I get this error: `. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file`

What action should I take now?

Edit: I'm using mac osx

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Mac osx

Comment: Sorry, MySQL on Mac OS X is sadly a bit out of my comfort zone, so I'll have to leave it for someone else to answer :)

Comment: Is mysql server running on the local machine?  Does `-u root` also say "access denied" or is it a different error?

Comment: yes its running on the same machine, and yes -u root also says access denied @wallyk